# Let $a\in\mathbb R^n$ be a fixed point. How to prove $B(a, 1/2)\cap B(g+a, 1/2)=\emptyset$ where $g\in \mathbb Z^n-\{0\}$?

Tags: geometry

Let $a\in\mathbb R^n$ be a fixed point. How to prove $B(a, 1/2)\cap B(g+a, 1/2)=\emptyset$ for some $g\in \mathbb Z^n-\{0\}$?

It sounds a silly question, and obvious one, but it is a fact I need for proving a result envolving group action..

I know I should proceed by contradiction but I wasn't able to show it. I have a feeling the contradiction will be $g=0$. Can anyone help me..

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: No, I need a formal proof despite the result being obvious..

Comment: A good picture is often the first step towards a formal proof.

Comment: I did several pictures and nothing ahaha

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Assume $x\in B(a,1/2) \cap B(g+a,1/2)$.
Then $\left|x - a\right| < 1/2$ and $\left|x - (g + a)\right| < 1/2$.
Use the triangle inequality to conclude something about $\left| g\right|$.

Comment: I did that but I got nowhere...

Comment: I've added more details.

Comment: I dit that too and I get only $|g|<1$, but I can't see why this is a contradiction..

Comment: You're almost done then. There is some precondition on $g$...

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see what Julien showed me: since $g\neq 0$ is an integer $g=(g_1, \ldots, g_n)$ with some $g_i\neq 0$ therefore $\|g\|^2=g_1^2+\ldots+g_n^2\geq 1$, a contradiction.. Thanks anyway =D

Answer (score 1):

Take $x$ in the intersection. That is $\|x-a\|<\frac{1}{2}$ and $\|x-a-g\|<\frac{1}{2}$.
Then
$$
\|g\|=\|(x-a)-(x-a-g)\|\leq\quad ?
$$

Comment: $\|g\|\leq \|x-a\|+\|x-(a+g)\|<1$ then?

Comment: @PtF There you go. Triangular inequality. And since $g\neq 0$...

Comment: but what contradiction that gives me?

Comment: @PtF  Since $g\neq 0$ has integer coordinates, $\|g \|^2=k_1^2+\ldots+k_n^2\geq 1$ because at least one $k_j$ is a nonzero integer.

Comment: Now I see ashashas, thanks, how didn't I think about it? Thanks for the help, that saved my life hahaha

Comment: @PtF It happens...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8053/discussion-between-ptf-and-julien)